# Bounty rewarded to false answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

Assume that a question has bounty and two answers. One answer is false. Bounty  rewarded to false answer. What then? It should be undone? can it be undone by the user who rewarded it ?

Comment: Is there an example? I would assume that the community would try to make it clear what the correct answer was by up-voting and down-voting.

Comment: It is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576713/deciding-whether-f-1-fa-a-or-ff-1b-b); its corrected after my comment (although still has excrescence parts).

Answer (score 7):

No, it should not be undone. Users are free to award their bounties to any answer, correct or wrong. Same as with voting.

An exception is reputation fraud: using bounties, or votes, solely as a way to inflate reputation of some users.

Comment: After [user 1's comment above](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23131/bounty-rewarded-to-false-answer#comment91370_23131) the question has changed to mean that the reward was a mistake, and the person who set the bounty wants to rectify that mistake.